# Ruby: How to find path relative to where class was instantiated?

Tags: ruby

I am creating a gem that is a Rack application, so I assume my application is going to be instantiated in a config.ru file. I expect certain paths to be relative to this config.ru file. So how can I get and set the path when the app is initialized?

For example:

Hidden away in my gem:

```
class MyApp
  def initialize
    @base_path = get_the_base_path_here
  end
  def call(env)
    html = render_view(@base_path + '/views/index.erb')
  end
end
```

User of the gem's config.ru:

```
require 'my_app'
run MyApp.new
```

...and their views directory:

```
/views
   index.erb
```

#### Update:

One way to achieve this is to pass in the base path as an argument, but I would like to find a way to achieve this without passing it as an argument.

```
require 'my_app'
run MyApp.new(File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Absolute Path of Current File

In general, you can simply use `File.expand_path(__FILE__)` to find the absolute path of the current file, which you can then store a variable or global if you like. For example:

```
$file_path = File.expand_path(__FILE__)
```

#### Absolute Path of Current Program

`File.expand_path($0)` is similar, but returns the program that was called. The distinction is sometimes subtle, but can be useful from time to time.

#### Creating an Absolute Path to a File in the Same Base Directory

If you want to use the directory name of the location of the current file to address another file, you can use File#join. For example:

```
File.join File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), '.X11-unix'
=> "/tmp/.X11-unix"
```

Comment: Actually I believe $0 will give the path to rackup in this case and __FILE__ will give the path to the gem source.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for providing different scenarios. I think `$0` is what I want to use with live code, but an interesting thing when I used it in my rspec test: `$0` was not the test file that was being run, but the actual rspec executable living inside the rspec gem. Anyway, it helped me to think creatively to come up with a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way but you can find config.ru with:

```
$:.find{|path| File.exists? "#{path}/config.ru"}
```